# DVI and DVI-to-HDMI fails to deliver signal to monitors when both are connected to a desktop

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi, graphics

I try to connect desktop to two screens:

```
1st monitor ----> DVI cable ----> desktop 
2nd monitor ----> DVI to HDMI cable ----> desktop
```

2nd screens returns 'no signal detected' when both monitors are connected. If I connect only one at a time they both work fine.

Desktop's graphics cards is built-in and has 1x VGA, 1x HDMI and 1x DVI port. I don't want to use VGA because images gets blurry.

Why I can't use DVI and DVI-to-HDMI cable at the same time?

Comment: You have not provided enough information at all. In what operating system?  Desktop Grafics card built-in, is it onboard only, then which motherboard is it?  What resolution are you in, because things like 4K res might not be supported twice? What do you see in the views in the display manager or device manager of the OS your running?

Comment: This is my Display Adapter: NVIDIA GeForce 7100. Display manager shows only 1 screen. Resolution is 1920x1080 on both screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please provide what exactly is the model of the GPU you have in your desktop?
Apparently in many cases, if GPU has VGA+DVI+HDMI setup, it means it has one analog and one digital output, that is:

- VGA as analog line (or VGA and DVI-A if present)
- DVI-D and HDMI as digital line

However, it does not apply for every GPU up on the market, so you can never be 100% sure. But in most cases that's the exact reason.
Please note that it can also be cable dependant and needs to be checked elsewhere to confirm.

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce 7100. I have just installed Radeon HD4300 and it picked up both screens with no fuss.